# How to use JSON:API spec "include" url param in Laravel 7.x project

Tags: json-api, laravel-7

I'm working on a Laravel 7.x application. I use Blade for the front-end but the application also exposes an API for some external hardware. I know that an JSON:API spec exists and want to follow it.

According to the JSON:API spec its possible to "fetch" objects including their relation(s) by using the `include=relation` url param. For example i want to fetch all posts with all its comments by using this url: `somedomain.com/posts?include=comments`.

I could achieve this with conditional arguments and conditional relationships (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#conditional-attributes) but than i need to write custom code for each possible include option. Is there an easy way to make Laravel "understand" this url param and include the relation in the response without writing code for each possible include option in the controller or resource?

Comment: Did you considered using an existing library to build a JSON:API complaint library with Laravel? [Laravel JSON API](https://laravel-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) gives you not only this feature for free.

Comment: I already found that library and considered to used it but its mentions explicitly `APIs to your Laravel 5 application` and i'm using Laravel 7 so i'm not sure if this is also supported for Laravel 7 and if yes, for how long ? (LTS) Maybe Laravel (7) has something on-board to support this feature?

Comment: Just outdated docs. The library supports Laravel 7.x in latest release. Still provides a lot of value in my opinion.